# Laravel via - ['nexmo'] did not work

Tags: api, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, vonage

Hi I am making laravel SMS Notification by using Nexmo API.

I have integrated nexmo as per given laravel documentation and as well as given in github.

My below code is working fine.

```
     Nexmo::message()->send([
        'to'   => 'xxxxxxx',
        'from' => 'xxxxxxx',
        'text' => 'Using the facade to send a message.'
     ]);
```

the above code is sending the SMS.

I need this to integrate as a Notification. but unfortunately `return ['nexmo']` did not work. It did not hit to `toNexmo($notifiable)` method in the notification.

Can anyone help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to send notifications via Nexmo - using the built in Notifications package and using the Nexmo client. You've implemented it using the client, but it looks as though you want to use the notifications package instead so that it calls `toNexmo`.

To send a notification via Laravel, dispatch it like this:

`Notification::send($yourUser, new SomethingNotification());`

The `SomethingNotification` definition looks like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage;

class SomethingNotification extends Notification
{
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['nexmo'];
    }

    public function toNexmo($notifiable)
    {
        return (new NexmoMessage)
            ->content('Some content');
    }
}
```

Comment: i implemented this but i get a ''Class 'Illuminate\Notifications\Message\NexmoMessage' not found"  FatalThrowableError...please help thanks

Answer (score 1):

#### You need to specify a `To` phone number on your User model:

```php
    public function routeNotificationForNexmo($notification)
    {
        return $this->phone_number;
    }
```